# A product of $\Bbb Z$ may not be a direct sum of $\Bbb Z$

Tags: direct-sum, free-abelian-group

I've tried to show that

A product of $\mathbb{Z}$ may not be a direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Since they are isomorphic when finite product, I thought that the infinite case matters.

I stuck here:

I may regard a member in a product of $\mathbb{Z}$ as

a function $X \to \mathbb{Z}$.

To get a contradiction, I might consider 'big' $X$.

However, what if there is soooo big Y such that the direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ –$Y$ times– is isomorphic to the product of 
$\mathbb{Z}$??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `free-abelian-group`?

Comment: any free abelian group is isomorpic to a direct sum of Z

Comment: i wanted to show a free abelian group is not isomorphic to a product of Z

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Z}\not\cong \bigoplus_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}$$

**Reason**:

$$|\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Z}|= \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = |\mathbb{R}|$$

while $$\left|\bigoplus_{z \in \mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}\right| = \aleph_0 = |\mathbb{N}|$$

Comment: my question is, when a product of Z fixed,(in your case Z-times) then direct sum of Z could be any "Y-times" it doesnt have to be Z-times like you ve shown. Thank though

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry.